# devise after sign in root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I want to set after sign in root path in devise this is my code in application controller

```
def signed_in_root_path(scope_or_resource)
if current_user.role == "dealer"
  dashboard_dealer_path
elsif current_user.role == "admin"
  admin_dashboard_path
else
  dashboard_customer_path
end
end
```

After sign in i should never be able to return to root page which is in routes.rb file

```
devise_scope :user do
  root :to => 'carinfos#index'
end
```

after sign in iam able to  go to carinfos/index page(i.e, i should not see localhost:3000), when i go to that page i should be redirected to dealer dashboard if logged as dealer

Answer (score 1):

In devise session controller there is a method called after_sign_in_path_for

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.role == "dealer"
      dashboard_dealer_path 
    elsif resource.role == "admin"
      admin_dashboard_path
   else
     dashboard_customer_path
   end
end
```

just override session controller

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
```

Comment: I tried it, and when i type localhost:3000 it is not redirecting me to localhost:3000/dashboard/dealer.and i think we can override in application controller itself right?

Comment: After sigin in it redirect to dashboard properly, if i type localhost:3000 it should redirect to dashboard if signed in so tried signed_in_root_path

Comment: in your application controller...check if user is not signed in redirect to sign_in path and when user signed_in then redirect to appropriate path

Comment: after user sign in he is redirected properly, but after sign in he should not be able to see the landing page/root page mentioned in routes

Comment: if user is dealer then redirect to dealer path and if admin then redirect to admin path.... u want to redirect in this manner right?

Comment: i have put another answer..just see that and i think it will solve your problem